# Arduino Ethernet.begin freezes if too much flash is used

Tags: c++, arduino

Arduino Mega 2560 appears to freeze infinitely on `Ethernet.begin()` if too much flash is used. 
When there is ~29% of used program storage space, `setup()` executes without any problems. However, when another ~30kB is added (~41% total), the sketch never finishes its setup. SD card is not inserted (works fine with ~29% used), verification/build/upload succeeds in both cases.
The following sketch demonstrates the issue:

```
#include <Ethernet.h>
#define TOO_MUCH 1
static const PROGMEM byte __attribute__((aligned(SPM_PAGESIZE))) data1[31488] = { 0 };
static const PROGMEM byte __attribute__((aligned(SPM_PAGESIZE))) data2[31488] = { 0 };
static const PROGMEM byte __attribute__((aligned(SPM_PAGESIZE))) data3[31488] = { 0 };//opted-out if not used

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  byte mac[6] = {0xC6, 0xB4, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x05};
  Serial.println("Starting ethernet");
  Ethernet.begin(mac);
  Serial.println("Started");//#IF TOO_MUCH this never executes
}


void loop() {
  static long lastTime = millis();
  if (millis() - lastTime > 2000) {
    lastTime = millis();
    Serial.println(pgm_get_far_address(data1));
    Serial.println(pgm_get_far_address(data2));//works fine if TOO_MUCH == 0
#if TOO_MUCH
    Serial.println(pgm_get_far_address(data3));//data3 opted-out if TOO_MUCH == 0
#endif
  }
}
```

Is there an error in this sketch? Is this a limitation of Arduion Mega 2560, to use just ~64kB out of 256kB total even when using `pgm_get_far_address`es?

Comment: `static long lastTime = millis();` This code is fishy, won't work in C. Are you sure this is not actually C++?

Comment: I don't think there is any overloaded print/println function for the far progmem pointer.  @Lundin Yes, Arduino uses `C++`.

Comment: And maybe you should try to move those arrays somewhere over 64kB and try to keep rest of the program under 64kB :)

Comment: @Lundin actually, I am not sure - Arduino c is probably mix of both. Will add tag... tag was added already.

Comment: @KIIV I am not aware of way that would allow me to explicitly select where the compiler allocates the arrays - is there one? The output of println is 32000 and 512 - it appear that the arrays were placed after my code (though not above 64k which seems to be the break point).

Comment: I can reproduce this without needing to use the Ethernet library.  I have an application where pinMode(A0, INPUT_PULLUP) won't set the pin mode correctly if I have much more than 64k of data.  Did you ever solve this?  I found an Arduino bug report describing something similar: https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/issues/2226

Comment: @MobyDisk sadly no, never solved it except not using the memory (using purely SD now).